# How do I maintain data from main Jframe?

Tags: java, swing, jframe

So I have this calculator when you first run it you will have to input name and section and then press submit and when you press submit 4 buttons will appear and each of those buttons will bring you to another JFrame. The problem is when I press back from that other JFrame it will direct me back from that main frame and you will again have to input name and section. How do I maintain the data which the user first inputted?

Comment: Your question in a little bit blurry. Please show the code in order to get better help.

Answer (score 0):

You can manage that using array of Jframes , when click frame you know the index of it

Answer (score 0):

May be beacuse you are `Extend`ing `JFrame`. Which is a bad habit .

Here I have done a short EG which creates the `Object` of respective `Frames` and calls the method
`setVisible(T/F)` accordingly :

```
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.*;


public class TestMultiFrames {
 JFrame mainFrame,frame2,frame3;

    public TestMultiFrames(){

        mainFrame =new JFrame();    
        frame2 =new JFrame();
        frame3 =new JFrame();
        JPanel p=new JPanel();

        JButton but1=new JButton("frame2");
        JButton but2=new JButton("frame3");
        JButton but3=new JButton("back to frame 3");
        p.add(but1);
        frame2.add(but2);
        frame3.add(but3);

        but1.addActionListener(new CustomActionListener1());
        but2.addActionListener(new CustomActionListener2());
        but3.addActionListener(new CustomActionListener3());

        mainFrame.add(p);
        mainFrame.setSize(200,200);
        frame2.setSize(200,200);
        frame3.setSize(200,200);
        mainFrame.setVisible(true);
    }

public static void main(String... args)
{
    new TestMultiFrames ();
}

class CustomActionListener1 implements ActionListener{
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        mainFrame.setVisible(false);
        frame2.setVisible(true);
        }
    }
class CustomActionListener2 implements ActionListener{
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            frame2.setVisible(false);
            frame3.setVisible(true);
            }
        }
class CustomActionListener3 implements ActionListener{
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                frame3.setVisible(false);
                frame2.setVisible(true);
                }
            }

}
```